# "If you asked me a question, I would give you an answer" vs. "If you ask me a question, I will give you an answer"

Tags: grammar

Somebody just told me that in BE one doesn't say "If you ask me a question, I will give you an answer". Instead, it should be "If you asked me a question, I would give you an answer". He said the first sentence is AE. Is that a fact? I am feeling very confused right now. Please help! Thank you!

Comment: "Somebody" ?    Please be a little more specific.  Was this a random person on the bus? Or a teacher?  A friend?  Why were you talking about dialect and English conditionals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are correct (in BrE and AmE) with slightly different meanings.

The first is a simple condition.  "If (something happens in the future, and it is quite likely to happen), then the consequence is (...)."  This is sometimes called the "first conditional"

The second gives a hypothetical but unreal condition.  This means that the condition is not likely: "I know you won't ask me a question, but if we imagine that you did, then the consequence would be (...).  This is sometimes called a second conditional.

The use of the past tense, and the use of "would" indicates that the condidtion is considered unreal:

> If I become a teacher, I will be kind to my students.

> If I became President, I would raise taxes and give the money to the poor.

The first example indicates that I think it is possible that I become a teacher.  The second suggests I think it is impossible that I become President.

British council have some [pages about conditionals](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/intermediate-to-upper-intermediate/conditionals-1). It is worth noting that not every conditional expression fits neatly into the zero-first-second-third conditional pattern (but many do)

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed explanations!